# Vaadin spring boot Frontend compiling failed

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin

I'm new in Vaading, and I'm trying to create an example project. During compiling Vaadin spring boot project,with this  pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>crud</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>crud</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>23.0.6</vaadin.version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-addons</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.crudui</groupId>
            <artifactId>crudui</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>collaboration-engine</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>23.0.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>production</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>23.0.6</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>frontend</id>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <productionMode>true</productionMode>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

After runngin this commands:

```
mvnw clean install

mvnw spring-boot:run
```

I receive many errors for modules not found in the folder projectname\target\flow-frontend\field-highlighter\src. The stanger think is that i do not see this target folder into root project. Same story if I run npm install, and execute again the above commands. Below are the specific error:

```
2022-04-17 22:56:41.659  INFO 12028 --- [onPool-worker-5] c.v.f.s.frontend.TaskUpdatePackages      : Frontend dependencies resolved successfully.
2022-04-17 22:56:44.249  INFO 12028 --- [onPool-worker-5] c.v.f.s.frontend.TaskCopyFrontendFiles   : Copying frontend resources from jar files ...
2022-04-17 22:56:44.308  INFO 12028 --- [onPool-worker-5] c.v.f.s.frontend.TaskCopyFrontendFiles   : Visited 17 resources. Took 58 ms.
2022-04-17 22:56:44.374  INFO 12028 --- [onPool-worker-5] c.v.b.devserver.AbstractDevServerRunner  : Starting Webpack
2022-04-17 22:56:44.568  INFO 12028 --- [onPool-worker-5] c.v.flow.server.frontend.FrontendTools   : Globally node version 10.15.3 is older than 16.14.0. Using node from C:\Users\davide\.vaadin.

------------------ Starting Frontend compilation. ------------------
2022-04-17 22:56:45.671  INFO 12028 --- [onPool-worker-5] c.v.b.devserver.AbstractDevServerRunner  : Running Webpack to compile frontend resources. This may take a moment, please stand by...
2022-04-17 22:56:50.311  INFO 12028 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : [webpack-dev-server] Project is running at:
2022-04-17 22:56:50.311  INFO 12028 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : [webpack-dev-server] Loopback: http://localhost:64731/
2022-04-17 22:56:50.312  INFO 12028 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : [webpack-dev-server] On Your Network (IPv4): http://192.168.1.189:64731/
2022-04-17 22:56:50.312  INFO 12028 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : [webpack-dev-server] Content not from webpack is served from 'C:\shared_folder\crud\target\classes\META-INF\VAADIN\webapp, C:\share
d_folder\crud\src\main\webapp' directory
2022-04-17 22:56:53.591  INFO 12028 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :
2022-04-17 22:56:53.591  INFO 12028 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : ERROR in ../target/flow-frontend/field-highlighter/src/vaadin-field-highlighter.js
2022-04-17 22:56:53.592  INFO 12028 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@polymer/iron-a11y-announcer/iron-a11y-announcer.js' in 'C:\shared_folder\crud\target\flow-
frontend\field-highlighter\src'
2022-04-17 22:56:53.592  INFO 12028 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   :
2022-04-17 22:56:53.592  INFO 12028 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : ERROR in ../target/flow-frontend/field-highlighter/src/vaadin-field-highlighter.js
2022-04-17 22:56:53.593  INFO 12028 --- [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@vaadin/vaadin-element-mixin/vaadin-dir-mixin.js' in 'C:\shared_folder\crud\target\flow-fro
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: You could try to update some versions: Vaadin -> 23.0.6, crudui -> 6.0.0, collaboration-engine -> 5.0.1 (you can actually remove collaboration engine dependency as it is available through vaadin-bom).

Comment: And once dependencies are updated, remove `node_modules` before trying to build again.